# Changing trigger event of MVC 2 client validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm developing a website using .NET 3.5 with MVC 2.0. For server side validations I'm using ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. These validations are reflected to client side by html helper's method `Html.EnableClientValidation()`.

This scheme works fine for except that it triggers the validation on blur event of each form control whereas I want to have it triggered on form's submit event.

Comment: Do you use standart or jQuery validation? For the standart validation start validate only on subbmit, and only then turns onblur and onchange event validation.

Comment: i m using standard validation provided by Microsoft and i want it to trigger only on onsubmit event. Furthermore i want to display these error messages in popup. i also considered using jquery for client validation but for jquery you have to write some code to bind it to the server side validation model you are using (DataAnnotation) in my case. the thing is that if you have to write custom js on client side than why not write ur own validators rather then writing the code to bind them to server validators